# ionic google maps geocoding on iOS not working

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, ionic-framework, google-geocoding-api

I have a google maps on one of my ionic pages. This map shows the residence of a person, I'm using geocoder to view this address on my google maps.

On Android this is working fine, but on iOS my map is blank (white page).

I think the problem is that for some reason there is no location set to the map and the map isn't rendered correctly due to this.

This piece of code is used for the address:

```
 geocoder.geocode({'address': $stateParams.location}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      console.log(results);
      start = results[0].geometry.location;
      map.setCenter(start);
      var marker = maps.createMarker(map, results[0].geometry.location, redMarker);
    } else {
      console.log("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
```

result is empty ([]) on iOS, but on Android it's filled with the correct information.

Can someone help me with this one?

Comment: Try to debug on your device with gapDebug and Show us the error please :)

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to see the error being returned to IOS. I could guess its something to do with Cross Website Scripting.